# VideoJS - videojs.getComponent(...) is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, compatibility, video.js

I am using a plugin that allows me to display an ad in video-js.

https://github.com/dirkjanm/videojs-preroll/blob/master/lib/videojs.ads.js

This worked perfect until version 5 but now that I have wanted to migrate to version 6, this plugin no longer works, the log throws me the following error:

```
TypeError: videojs.getComponent(...) is undefined               videojs.ads.js:386
```

It seems that everything lies in this section of the plugin (line 386):

```
    (function() {
      var
        videoEvents = videojs.getComponent('Html5').Events,
        i,
        returnTrue = function() { return true; },
        triggerEvent = function(type, event) {
          // pretend we called stopImmediatePropagation because we want the native
          // element events to continue propagating
          event.isImmediatePropagationStopped = returnTrue;
          event.cancelBubble = true;
          event.isPropagationStopped = returnTrue;
          player.trigger({
            type: type + event.type,
            state: player.ads.state,
            originalEvent: event
          });
},
```

The plugin has not been updated since a while ago so I also gave some alarms on how to register the plugin but that yes I could solve it, I'm not very understanding of javascript so I do not know how I could solve that.

Answer (score 2):

Ok comrades, I have been reading the manual of videojs 6 and apparently to solve that problem only had to change a line:

```
videojs.getComponent -to- videojs.getTech
```

I leave it here in case someone has the same problem.
Of course, I am not a Javascript specialist so I honestly would not know how to give an explanation about this.